# Div is not hidden after calling Page_ClientValidate

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

The following code does not hide the  "info" DIV and show the "questions" DIV when Page_ClientValidate is called sets isValid to true. If I set isValid to true or false, it works as expected. 
Why does Page_ClientValidate prevent the hide/show behaviour to occur?

```
function hide() {
        var isValid = Page_ClientValidate('validInfo');
        if (isValid) {
            if (!$('[id$=chkConfirm]').is(':checked'))
            { alert("Please confirm and agree with conditions"); }
            else {
                $('#info').hide();
                $('#questions').show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the HTML - I shortened it to the main parts and there are only some more txtBoxes and radioLists in the DIVS:

```
 <div id="info">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tBoxTradingName" runat="server" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tBoxTradingName"
        ValidationGroup="validInfo">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkConfirm" Text=" I confirm that the information provided above is accurate."
        runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnNext" Text="Next >>" runat="server" OnClientClick="hide()" Width="100"
        CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="validInfo" />
</div>
<div id="questions" style="display:none;">
    <div class="label">
        Do you trade as a
    </div>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rBtnTradeAs" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Sole Proprietor</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Company</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Closed Corporation</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Trust</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Other (please specify)</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxTradeAs" runat="server" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator30" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rBtnTradeAs"
        ErrorMessage="Required">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the HTML code as well...

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes I have. It goes into the else part, but the DIVs do not change - the page just scrolls to the top.

Comment: can we see some html code as well?

Comment: @EwaldStieger: Yes of course, because the page is posted back to the server and will be recreated so your clientside change is lost. If you're posting back anyway, you could simply switch the visibility on serverside in the button(?)-click event handler.

Comment: Is it called on a link or form? Might be because you dont cancel the default behaviour.

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen It is called from a button - OnClientClick

Comment: @Ewald-Is the above function is in document.ready() ?

Comment: @DotNetter Check the answer that I accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling a clientside function on a `Button`'s `OnCLientClick`. Then you want to change visibility of some controls via javascript if `Page_ClientValidate` returns `true`.

The problem is: the button will cause a postback if no Validator bites. The postback will cause the page to be recreated on serverside so that every clientside change is lost.

So either

- don't postback (returning `false` from `OnCLientClick` will prevent a postback) or
- change visibility of the controls on serverside(by adding `runat="server" to your divs)`